# Matplotlib does not draw more than one scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote a python script for data analyses. The result is one figure with multiple scatter in it. Everythink works fine but due too complexity I refactored the script and build a class with several methods to keep it more simple and to have a better overview. But now one of my scatters is not drawn any more and I can't figure out why. The code is almost exactly the same. Just split up into several methods. The code looks like the following:

```
def _setup_plot_window(self):
    t1 = time.time()
    ax = self.ax
    P = self.P
    Proj = self.Proj
    GM = self.GM

    ax.set_xlim(Proj.west_most_longitude - self.BORDER_MARGIN, 
                Proj.east_most_longitude + self.BORDER_MARGIN)

    ax.set_ylim(Proj.south_most_latitude - self.BORDER_MARGIN, 
                Proj.north_most_latitude + self.BORDER_MARGIN)

    paths_xy = []
    for p in self.paths:
        p_xy = [Proj.project_to_xy(x[0], x[1]) for x in p]
        paths_xy.append(p_xy)

    tram_stops_X = []; tram_stops_Y = []
    for i, coord_name in self.trams.iteritems():
        lat, lon, n = coord_name
        tram_stops_X.append(lon)
        tram_stops_Y.append(lat)
        plt.text(lon, lat, n, fontsize=10, clip_on=True)

    for p in paths_xy:
        y = map(lambda x:x[0], p)
        x = map(lambda x:x[1], p)
        line = Line2D(x, y, lw=1, color='g')
        ax.add_line(line)

    line_top    = Line2D([GM.lon_max, GM.lon_max], [GM.lat_min, GM.lat_max], c='g', linestyle = '--', lw=1)
    line_bottom = Line2D([GM.lon_min, GM.lon_min], [GM.lat_min, GM.lat_max], c='g', linestyle = '--', lw=1)
    line_left   = Line2D([GM.lon_min, GM.lon_max], [GM.lat_min, GM.lat_min], c='g', linestyle = '--', lw=1)
    line_right  = Line2D([GM.lon_min, GM.lon_max], [GM.lat_max, GM.lat_max], c='g', linestyle = '--', lw=1)
    ax.add_line(line_top)
    ax.add_line(line_bottom)
    ax.add_line(line_left)
    ax.add_line(line_right)

    ax.scatter(tram_stops_X, tram_stops_Y, c='r', marker='x')
    xp, yp = separate_particles_in_list(P.particles)
    plot_particles, = ax.plot(xp, yp, c='b', marker='o', linestyle='None')
    #ax.scatter(xp, yp, c='b', marker='o')

    plt.show()
    print 'Time "Setup plot window": ', (time.time()-t1) / 60, ' min'
```

Near the end of the code are two ax.scatter(...). The first one is drawn, the second one is not being drawn. I also tried it for the xp, yp data with ax.plot(...) but also this is not drawn. I checked xp, yp in the debugger, they are equaly filled with data.

Does anybody knows what is wrong?

Comment: well, in its current state, the second ax.scatter() is commented out. More seriously, the code isn't complete, so I can't run it to see what happens to the second ax.scatter(). Put in some dummy data and enough of the includes for it to run, and it will be easier for other people to check.

Comment: @cphlewis, well, I know its commented out because I tried it with the line above instead. Its not so simple to make it run because it needs a lot of code from a few custom modules. I think I can't just simply fix the imports without alter the behavior of the program. I hoped only the function is enough to find the error cause the complete plotting stuff happens there.

Comment: Now it's not clear to me what the problem is. I assumed you wanted to plot tram_stops_X, tram_stops_Y and also xp, yp on one plot. Yes? No? Where are the "two ax.scatter(...)" and in what context are they called?

Anyway, having a piece of code that's so entangled with other custom modules may *be* the problem. My debugging strategy would be to cut out elegancies (e.g., everything involving GM) until the code either worked, or was simple enough for anyone to run the sample.